# Filter Criteria "Workbench Moderation: Current" only works on published revisions?

Tags: views

I added the following filter criteria to a View:

Workbench Moderation: Current

However, after not seeing the output I expected, I realized that this filter only displays a revision if the revision is both current **AND** published. If a draft is currently current, then it is ignored by the filter.

Is that a bug?

Thanks,

Stephen Gilson

Comment: I think you'll need to ask the module maintainer this question, it's going to be very hard for anyone to speculate on whether or not this is a bug without intimate knowledge of what the module is _supposed_ to do

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer in this post: https://drupal.org/node/1947732

From that post:

"The key is when you create the view, you need to set it to show content revisions rather than content. They mysql query used when showing content revisions is different than when showing content. One pulls data from the node table, the other pulls from the revisions table. The latter is what you want when dealing with revisions. In my testing so far, the Workbench Moderation: Current filter works fine in a content revision view."